# When is getattr() not like normal attribute access?

Tags: python

Is there any difference between this code, which uses dot notation for attribute access:

```
def get_foo(self):
    try:
        return self._attribute
    except AttributeError:
        self._attribute = 'something'
        return self._attribute
```

And the following code, which uses the `getattr` function:

```
def get_foo(self):
    try:
        return getattr(self, '_attribute')
    except AttributeError:
        self._attribute = 'something'
        return self._attribute
```

They seem to behave the same way to me, but I came across the latter example in some code and I was curious why one would opt for calling `getattr()` in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), they are equivalent (unless a third argument is provided to suppress the `AttributeError` when the attribute is not present).

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. *name* must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. **For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`.** If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

I can't think of many reasons to prefer `getattr` over normal dot notation here . . . The only time I can think where I might be tempted to use the former is if I was trying to prevent my linter from complaining about `protected-access` (which is probably best disabled with a pragma if you have a legitimate reason for doing it). . .

Answer (score 2):

These are equivalent, however `getattr` can take an optional default value to be returned when the attribute does not exist, e.g.

`getattr(self, '_attribute', None)`

Thus, the second function can alternatively be written without try/catch (assuming `self._attribute` can't be `None`):

```
def get_foo(self):
    attr = getattr(self, '_attribute', None)
    if attr is None:
        self._attribute = 'something'
    return attr
```

Comment: That's not quite the same -- the original function will preserve a value of `None`, but your version will replace it with `'something'`.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers provide, the two are functionally the same thing without the third argument.

One trivial difference is that they do not have the same effect on the stack; this is at best a code-golfy difference, and could only come up in very contrived scenarios (perhaps testing to see if you were in "debug" mode and providing different timings, if you were a malicious QA person).

```
import inspect

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 3

    @property
    def x(self):
        curframe = inspect.currentframe()
        calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)      
        print(calframe[1][2])
        return self._x

f = Foo()
def bar():
    print( f.x )    
    # if instead we use the print statement on the next line,
    # we note that there is one more stack frame. In no universe
    # is this particularly impact, but in a closed test case
    # we would be able to determine which one was being used
    #print( getattr(f,'x') )

bar()
```

Comment: bravo! (here are > 9 more characters)

Comment: How do we 'note that there is one more stack frame' ? `print(len(calframe))` seems to output `3` in both cases.